# overloaded method value route with alternatives

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, specs2

I'm getting this error (overloaded method ) for method route, status, contentAsJson. Any ideas why?

```
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers
import play.api.libs.json.Json


class ItemsSpec extends PlaySpecification  {
  "Items controller" should {
    "list items" in new WithApplication {
      route(FakeRequest(controllers.routes.Items.list())) match {
        case Some(response) =>
          status(response) must equalTo (OK)
          contentAsJson(response) must equalTo (Json.arr())
        case None => failure
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it will matter here or not, but in [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2) they recommend doing the following import:

```
import play.api.test.Helpers._
```

and you imported only `import play.api.test.Helpers`.